# Perl: Define variable in caller context

Tags: perl

I have created this simple subroutine.

```
use List::Util qw(pairmap);

sub pairGroupBy(&@) {
  my($irCode, @iaItems) = @_;

  my %laResult = ();
  pairmap {
    my $lsKey = $irCode->();
    if (!defined($lsKey)) {
      die "Trying to pairGroup by nonexisting key '$lsKey'";
    }
    push @{$laResult{$lsKey}}, $a => $b;
  } @iaItems;

  return %laResult;
}
```

It works well until the subroutine is used from the same file where it is defined. When I move it to some package then variables `$a` and `$b` becomes undefined inside the `$irCode->()` callback.

I have learned from the [List::Util source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JHI/perl-5.8.1/ext/List/Util/lib/List/Util.pm) that this code do the trick:

```
my $caller = caller;
local(*{$caller."::a"}) = \my $a;
local(*{$caller."::b"}) = \my $b;
```

So I'have modified my subroutine in this way:

```
use List::Util qw(pairmap);

sub pairGroupBy(&@) {
  my($irCode, @iaItems) = @_;

  my $caller = caller;

  my %laResult = ();
  pairmap {

    no strict 'refs';
    local(*{$caller."::a"}) = \$a; # <---- the line 96
    local(*{$caller."::b"}) = \$b;

    my $lsKey = $irCode->();
    if (!defined($lsKey)) {
      die "Trying to pairGroup by nonexisting key '$lsKey'";
    }
    push @{$laResult{$lsKey}}, $a => $b;
  } @iaItems;

  return %laResult;
}
```

But I need to use the `no strict 'refs';` line (the [List::Util source code](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JHI/perl-5.8.1/ext/List/Util/lib/List/Util.pm) does not use it). Otherwise the error message appears:

```
Can't use string ("main::a") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at /home/.../bin/SatFunc.pm line 96.
```

My question is: Is there some better way how to define `$a` and `$b` variables in the caller's context without using `no strict 'refs';`?

I want my function will be used in the same way as [pairmap](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#pairmap), [pairgrep](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#pairgrep) etc.

**EDIT**:
@simbabque asked for an example, how the function is used. So this is an example:

```
my %laHoH = (
  aa => {
    color => 'yellow',
    item => 'sun',
    active => 1
  },
  bb => {
    color => 'blue',
    item => 'sky',
    active => 1
  },
  cc => {
    color => 'green',
    item => 'grass',
    active => 0
  },
  dd => {
    color => 'blue',
    item => 'watter',
    active => 1
  }
);


my %laGrouped = pairGroupBy {
  $b->{color}
} pairgrep {
  $b->{active}
} %laHoH;
```

The function then returns this structure:

```
{
  'yellow' => [
                'aa',
                {
                  'color' => 'yellow',
                  'item' => 'sun',
                  'active' => 1
                }
              ],
  'blue' => [
              'dd',
              {
                'active' => 1,
                'item' => 'watter',
                'color' => 'blue'
              },
              'bb',
              {
                'color' => 'blue',
                'item' => 'sky',
                'active' => 1
              }
            ]
};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include example calls to your `pairGroupBy` function.

Comment: No, no better way really if you want that behavior.  The package has that code `eval`-ed if XS doesn't load and that global `$a`, `$b` are declared (with `use vars`, which "_has been superseded by `our`_")

Comment: You should just do `no strict 'refs';` (in the smallest possible scope).  List::Util doesn't need to do so because it is not using strict at all, but you don't want to follow it in doing _that_.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're seeing that problem, but I suspect you're overthinking matters. Using `pairmap` in void context like that seems a bad idea.

Can't you just convert your array into a hash and then iterate across that?

```
my %iaItemsHash = @iaItams;

while (my ($k, $v) = each %iaItemsHash) {
  my $lsKey = $irCode->();
  if (!defined($lsKey)) {
    die "Trying to pairGroup by nonexisting key '$lsKey'";
  }
  push @{$laResult{$lsKey}}, $k => $v;
}
```

**Update:** In light of your comment, I've re-read your original question and spotted that you are talking about accessing the variables with the `$irCode->()` call.

The problem with my solution is that `$k` and `$v` are lexical variables and, therefore, aren't available outside of their lexical scope (this is generally seen as a feature!) The solution is to resort to good programming practice and to send the values into the subroutine as parameters.

Comment: You are right that while loop is better in this case than pairmap in void context. But my question is still not answered. In this case I'm able to access `$k` and `$v` variables from the `$irCode->()` callback only when the caller and this subroutine are both in the same package.

Comment: According to you updated answer: You mean that functions like [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) or [reduce](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#reduce) are wrong and I should not create these kind of functions?

Comment: No. I mean that features like `sort` or `reduce` should only be created when absolutely necessary. And in this case, it really doesn't look at all necessary. Unless you have a very good reason, a subroutine should only ever access data that is passed to it.

Comment: OK. Let imagine that I have some good reason. How I can do it? My question is not about the reason but about the way ho I can pass variables to the callback in the same way as the sort function does.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is there some better way how to define `$a` and `$b` variables in the caller's context without using `no strict 'refs';?`*

You're asking us how to perform symbolic dereferences while asking Perl to prevent you from symbolic deferences. There's no reason to do that. If you want to perform symbolic dereferences, don't ask Perl to prevent you from doing it.

Even if Perl doesn't catch you doing it (i.e. if you manage to find a way to not trigger `use strict qw( refs );`), you'll still be using symbolic dereferences! You'd just be lying to yourself and to your readers.

Instead, it's best to document what you are doing. Use `no strict qw( refs );` to signal that you are using doing something `use strict qw( refs );` is suppose to block.

---

The following approach for building the same structure as your code is much less wasteful:

```
my %laGrouped;
for my $key (keys(%laHoH)) {
   my $rec = $laHoH{$key};
   next if !$rec->{active};
   push @{ $laGrouped{ $rec->{color} } }, $key, $rec;
}
```

But let's improve the structure as well. The following approach produces a structure that's easier to use:

```
my %laGrouped;
for my $key (keys(%laHoH)) {
   my $rec = $laHoH{$key};
   next if !$rec->{active};
   $laGrouped{ $rec->{color} }{$key} = $rec;
}
```

---

If you find yourself using `pairGroupBy`, you've probably went wrong somewhere. But here's a better implementation of it for educational purposes:

```
sub pairGroupBy(&@) {
   my $cb = shift;

   my $caller = caller;
   my $ap = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{ $caller.'::a' } };  local *$ap;
   my $bp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{ $caller.'::b' } };  local *$bp;

   my %groups;
   while (@_) {
      *$ap = \shift;
      *$bp = \shift;
      my $group = $cb->();
      push @{ $groups{$group} }, $a, $b;
   }

   return %groups;
}
```